# Spring Boot Validation - How to return only one error from field

Tags: spring, validation

I'd like to create application to validate provided data by user. Here is an example.

**Word.java**

```
@Data
class Word {    
    @NotBlank(message = "Please, enter your text")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Your text is too short")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]+[a-z]+$", message = "Your text is incorrect")
    private String text;
}
```

I want to validate `text` field and I wat to view only one error, for example:

for input `{text: ""}`:
expected output should be `Please, enter your text`,
but actual output is:  `Please, enter your text, Your text is too short, Your text is incorrect`

for input `{text: "ab"}`
expected output should be `Your text is too short`
but actual output is: `Your text is too short, Your text is incorrect`

I tried to do custom validator with `@ReportAsSingleViolation` annotation but there was no changes.

Do you know, how to solve it? Thank you for all your answers.

**EDIT**
Sometimes errors are not in correct order, but I don't know why. For example

for input `{text: ""}`:
expected output should be `Please, enter your text`,
but actual output is:  `Your text is incorrect, Your text is too short, Please, enter your text`

Comment: write a controllerAdvice where you can catch this sort of exception. And the after catching return the exception with whatever message you want

Comment: I thought about it, but if I want to have multiple fields, it could be hard to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but missing few things. After adding your oval validations you need to implement a method which takes in your object and validate it against the oval.

Your example shows that you have done this but you're printing all of them instead make different cases to throw different exceptions.

Following is the example -

```
public static Set<ConstraintViolation> getOvalViolations(Object obj){

    Validator validator = new Validator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation> violations = new HashSet(validator.validate(obj));

    return violations;
}
```

This will get you a set of ConstraintViolation and you can use the one you want to throw from the list. You can check for the primary exception for each case and throw them appropriately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm... seems to be good solution, but how to implement them? Where to put this method? Into `@Configuration` bean?

Comment: As you can see I made this method as a static method. You can do the same and load it from Utils project/common template package. This will help you in calling it multiple time. You can call it like - ClassName. getOvalViolations(obj);

Comment: OK, but I don't know, why Application throws errors not in correct order. This solution is good but my errors are not in correct order.

Comment: you should try using TreeSet to maintain the ordering.

Comment: if you're satisfied with the answer, please put a tick.